# How much cache-space will browsers use?

Tags: caching, browser, filesystems, local-storage, browser-cache

I'm curious how many MB/GB the various browsers will cache before prematurely deleting older cache files. Do you know? For bonus points, in which order will the cached files be deleted (beyond the ones which have expired).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends entirely on what the browser's preferences are set to.

#### Example (Firefox 4):

[image]

#### Example (IE 8):

[image]

#### Bonus points time

Typical [cache expiration algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) are

- [LFU (least frequently used)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least-Frequently_Used) and
- [LRU (least recently used)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used)

Comment: Thank you. To add to this, FFX 4 is now defaulting to 250MB, Chrome ~100MB, ie7+ ~1GB

Comment: @Matrym: it may depend on your system. I **just** installed my OS today, so that install of FF4 is about as clean as it gets, and you can see that it's defaulting to 1024 MB (1 GB) for me. I have a 1 TB drive in my machine; that may be the answer. Does your computer have a 250 GB drive?

Comment: I was actually referring to this: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/firefox4beta4/   ... Although when going into my settings, I see the same thing you do. I think I'm going to have to just force my computer to download a constant stream of large video files, set to cache, and see where it stops.